# Errors in Embedded elastic search server in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, junit

I'm trying to run embedded elastic servers for Junit test cases. So I just extended a class ESIntegTestCase. But it's not allowing me to run the test case. I use elastic search 6.0.0.

```
import org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AbstractElasticsearchTest extends ESIntegTestCase {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase d;
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context information for thread: Thread[id=12, name=Thread-1, state=RUNNABLE, group=TGRP-AbstractElasticsearchTest]. Is this thread running under a class com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner runner context? Add @RunWith(class com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class) to your test class. Make sure your code accesses random contexts within @BeforeClass and @AfterClass boundary (for example, static test class initializers are not permitted to access random contexts).
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedContext.context(RandomizedContext.java:248)
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedContext.current(RandomizedContext.java:134)
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.augmentStackTrace(RandomizedRunner.java:1848)
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RunnerThreadGroup.uncaughtException(RunnerThreadGroup.java:20)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1959)
```

It seems issue with Spring Boot jars, When I run the same with separate project it works fine. please help me to resolve

Dependencies:

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <es.version>6.0.0</es.version>
    <flyway-maven-plugin.version>5.1.1</flyway-maven-plugin.version>
    <postgres.version>5.1.1</postgres.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${es.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>${es.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <version>${es.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>securemock</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedded-database-spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It seems a dependency problem. Please post your deps config file as well as it's impossible to diagnose a problem merely from the test code

Comment: It seems issue with Spring Boot jars, When I run the same with separate project it works fine

Comment: Ok, few more suggestions: try the command `mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=/path/to/file` : it will export the entire dependency tree so you can search for jars with same name but different versions. Alternatively (it could happen that the same class is in jars with different names), in your IDE you can use the autocomplete suggestion box to find the source of the ESTestCase class (modern IDEs would display 2 classes and the package name which contains them). Finally, if nothing works, you can try this maven plugin [duplicate-finder](https://github.com/basepom/duplicate-finder-maven-plugin/wiki)